# Mathematica: change all text fonts simultaneosly in Plot or Listplot

Tags: fonts, styles, plot, wolfram-mathematica, font-size

I would like to change the font size of all texts in Plot and ListPlot with one command. I remember doing this in the past with a single SetOptions[Plot, ...] call for each (ListPlot and Plot), but now I seem to need to run this command once for each option, so once for LabelStyle and once for AxesStyle and so on.

Is there a solution to this? I really remember doing this a few weeks ago, but forgot it!!

Thanks for any efforts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After an hour of searching, I think I found the answer to be BaseStyle, so it looks like that:

```
SetOptions[Plot, BaseStyle -> FontSize -> 18]
```

Thanks anyway :)

If you find this answer not convincing, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs you may prefer to use `GraphicsBoxOptions`.  See these answers for examples:

[Keeping Text Size the Same Throughout Entire Notebook File](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1983/121)

[Set default font for Output](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10779/121)

This option, and related options for other Box types, sets style according to the type of low-level Box output, such as `GraphicsBox` (boxes are the data sent to the Front End for display).  If you want to affect the style of all 2D graphics output at once, rather than by function (`Plot`, `LogPlot`, etc.), this is the way to do it.